# Sort Photos in a Views Block by Weight

Tags: views

We created a custom Views block that shows a user's uploaded photos in a grid. Drupal has the draggable feature and users can edit the order of these images. However, I cannot see the sort by weight option. I know I can add it via Relationships but I don't see it there neither.

Comment: Maybe you need the weight module https://drupal.org/project/Weight

Comment: This is a great solution. However, it is not working on my site. I believe it has to do with the custom content type created. Since it is an issue related to the site, not Drupal, I think I will need to find a custom solution.